Datagridview search
I'm trying to set up a datagridview search using a combobox. When you enter part of the search word into the combo box, the search does not occur. To be successful, you must enter the entire word. How can I make the search return all results that match part of the word?
...
$DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "User Name"
...
# Search Button
$Button1.Add_Click(
{
$selected_user = $ComboBox1.SelectedItem    
foreach ($Row in $dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if ($Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() -match $selected_user) {
        $DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $true
    }
    else {
        $DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $false
    }
 }
})


It's probably wrong to search in all rows if usernames are only in the first column

Instead of match use " $Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith('abc')  Powershell is built using Net library and strings in Net have the method StartsWith.

Can you give an example of a username and search term that are failing to match? Also, I’m pretty sure you can simplify your code to $row.Visible = $Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() -match $selected_user

For example: searching for user Baggins Frodo.
I enter “b”, “ba”, “bag” into the combo box - no result. Only last and first names in full.

$Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith('abc')
'$selected_user' - this is a variable. I think need regular expressions instead of 'abc'.

Try SelectedText instead of SelectedItem - the latter is only populated if the text exactly matches an item in the drop-down list and is $null otherwise - that’s why partial text like “bag” doesn’t match anything, because SelectedItem is still null, but SelectedText will contain “bag”. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#property-value

It doesn't work with $ComboBox1.SelectedText either. It seems to me that the problem is precisely in $ComboBox1.SelectedText. I just enter 'baggins' instead, the search even starts with the initial letters.

Earned with
$Row.Visible = $Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() -match $ComboBox1.Text

Final result:
$Button1.Add_Click(
{
$selected_user = '^' + [regex]::escape($ComboBox1.Text)
foreach ($Row in $dataGridView1.Rows) {    
$Row.Visible = $Row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() -match $selected_user
}
})

